# Defining the same predicate three times

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and I had a question about defining predicates. I am reading some code where the same fact is defined more than once:

```
sister(jenny, sarah).
sister(jenny, sarah).
sister(jenny, sarah).
```

From what I understand, this is a fact representing that jenny and sarah are sisters but this code is repeated three times. What significance does this have?

Comment: It's redundant information. You've stated 3 times that `jenny` is sister of `sarah`. And if you query, `sister(X, Y)` you'll get the same answer 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

```
sister(jenny, sarah).
sister(jenny, sarah).
sister(jenny, sarah).
```

> What significance does this have?

None. It is a mistake.

---

With regards to

> this is a function

Prolog does not have functions, only predicates.

With regards to

> same predicate three times

Those are not predicates, those are facts because they have no `:-` or [body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog_syntax_and_semantics#Prolog_programs).